# How to build Angular 4 Component Library with the Angular CLI + ng-packagr + state mgmt?

Tags: angular, node-modules, ngrx, state-management

Trying to wrap up my head around creating an angular node module that will have a state mgmt Ngrx.

I've been building node  module using this guide: https://medium.com/@nikolasleblanc/building-an-angular-4-component-library-with-the-angular-cli-and-ng-packagr-53b2ade0701e

Currently stuck at introducing ngrx child state, so that when I download from NPM my module, I can somehow define for to be part of my main app state mgmt.

As I understand I can do this somehow going the root of using/setting up ModuleWithProviders

Comment: not the answer but a place to gain more knowledge about the subject and maybe you can get to there by yourself.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EoSn8qASqQA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [yeoman generator](https://github.com/jvandemo/generator-angular2-library) to make your library seed and add the `ngrx` features or anything you want to add.

So `ng-packagr` is not necessary because the starter kit is prepared to compile `AOT` angular libraries by default.